# MsiGetProductInfo() - "invalid parameter"

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling, windows-installer

I want to get the install date of product:

```
DWORD max = 255;
WCHAR buffer[255];
std::wstring guidWString = S::WstrToStr(subKeys[i]); //from array of std::string
LPCWSTR guid = guidWString.c_str();
int err = MsiGetProductInfo(guid, INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLDATE, buffer, &max);
if(err == ERROR_SUCCESS){ //never success :(
    info.date = S::WstrToStr(std::wstring(buffer));
}
```

But I always get the error code 87 (*ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER*).
I don't see anything "invalid" here, according to the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**I have checked that:**

1. All variables are of **good types**, buffer size (`DWORD max`) is **not null**, **equal to the size of my buffer**.
2. I use a function to convert `std::string` (I have my GUID in `std::string`) to `std::wstring` (**under debugger, all looks good, conversion works** in many other places in code that use WinAPI and `std::wstring`).
3. I have tried with **different GUID**, all of them exists and works for asking register "manually". `MsiGetProductInfo()` returns that error **ALWAYS**.
4. I have also tried to just **write GUID in code** (`L"{GUID-GO-EXACTLY-HERE}"`), with the same result.

**I just don't know where the problem is?**

Comment: Do you enclose the GUID with curly brackets? (as in L"{GUID-GO-EXACTLY-HERE}")

Comment: Yes, I have tried with {} as well as without them. Parsing that GUID when I use registry operations instead of MsiGetProductInfo works well, so I guess GUIDs are correct.